# sql statement to fetch data from the database of exactly 5 days past

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

I was working on something and I needed to query a record from the database that is exactly 5 days from now, but it did not work as expected.

I have tried something but it's just fetching record of from 5 days till now. All I wanted is the record of exactly 5 days past (or ago). Here is my code, please tell me want I am not doing right.

```
SELECT * FROM ts_user
WHERE user_registerdate >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 5 day) AND user_registerdate <= CURDATE()
ORDER BY user_registerdate DESC;
```

Comment: What data type is user_registerdate?

Comment: Have you tried = instead of >=?

Comment: user_registerdate is a name of a date field in the database

Comment: What did not work?

Comment: I am guessing the problem is he just wants the records that was 5 days ago and just that day, not all from then to now. I dont have access to a mysql right now so i can't help you with a working solution myself.

Comment: it's not fetching exactly 5 days from now, it's just fetching from 5 days up till now. that is it's fetching 5,4,3,2,1 days. all i wanted is for it to fetch just exactly 5 day @maSTAShuFu

Comment: Why then are you testing for >=?

Comment: You might want to post a sample data and expected output

Comment: your query is absolutely correct. you have to do more debug in your code and check the DB field type and date format.

Answer (score 1):

If user_resgisterdate field from your database is DateTime 
Try this

```
SELECT * FROM ts_user 
WHERE Datediff(day,user_registerdate,getdate()) <= 5;
```

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks, it's working now. i really do appreciate everyone effort. Thanks once again. you  guys are the best

Answer (score 0):

This gets exactly 5 days ago,

```
SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(user_registerdate, '%m/%d/%Y') 
FROM ts_user  
WHERE DATE(user_registerdate) = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 5 DAY;
```

Comment: Thanks mariam, this really help